# Keycloak override default SPI with Docker

Tags: java, docker, keycloak, keycloak-services, service-provider

I have created my custom SPI for brute-force detection. On local env I just added this in standalone-ha.xml:

```
        <spi name="bruteForceProtector">
            <default-provider>bw-brute-force-detector</default-provider>
            <provider name="bw-brute-force-detector" enabled="true">
            </provider>
        </spi>
```

This doesn't work anymore when we are using Docker. How I can pack and override default SPI with docker? I saw some approach with cli scrips but there is no clear example so I can understand...
Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

1. Create your own cli script:

   ```
   embed-server --server-config=standalone-ha.xml --std-out=echo
   batch

   /subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=bruteForceProtector:add
   /subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=bruteForceProtector/provider=custom-brute-force-detector:add(enabled=true)
   /subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=bruteForceProtector:write-attribute(name=default-provider, value=custom-brute-force-detector)

   run-batch
   stop-embedded-server
   ```
2. Create sh script that runs cli script:

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash
   if [ "$ADD_CUSTOM_BRUTE_FORCE_SPI" == "true" ]; then
       echo "Enabling custom brute force detector"
       $JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --file="/opt/jboss/tools/cli/infinispan/custom-brute-force-detector.cli"
   fi
   ```
3. Import it in Dockerfile:

   ```
   RUN chmod +755 /opt/jboss/startup-scripts/add-custom-brute-force-spi.sh /opt/jboss/tools/docker-entrypoint.sh
   ```